# Resolution of a DNS-Name, which includes a single Number (e.g. x.x.x.1)

Tags: java, dns, windows-10

I have a Problem with Java InetAddress, when I try to resolve the DNS-Name with this. I found out that the problem occurs, when the DNS-Name includes a single number. The following line shows an example. The problem must be the single number (here 1), cause when I write x.x.x.1a everthing works fine.

`InetAddress.getByName("x.x.x.1")`

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your problem is not specific to Java. Any application on the system will hit the RFC rule @Andy highlighted to you as this is done by OS functions related to name resolution. What is your goal in naming servers like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123#section-2.1) (emphasis mine):

> However, a valid host name can never
> have the dotted-decimal form `#.#.#.#`, **since at least the
> highest-level component label will be alphabetic**.

`x.x.x.1` just isn't a valid host name.

Comment: I don't think so... I make another example: www.google.com and this is a valid host name. To be concret in my case the host name ist eg. a.tcms.idu.1 and here the single number (here 1) makes the problem. Hope you know what I mean.

Comment: @Pacin the highest level component of `www.google.com`, `com`, is alphabetic; in fact, there are no numbers at all, so I don't know what you are trying to show.

Comment: FWIW, there was the `.42` registry project see https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2179216 (or in French: https://www.numerama.com/magazine/17668-des-noms-de-domaine-en-42-pour-un-web-libre-et-ouvert.html) and it worked (it is now dead).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek "Before anyone wonders: No, this isn't an official TLD. The domains you register there won't resolve for anyone unless they futz with their nameserver settings."

Comment: @Pacin do not name your servers like that, because you hit the rule highlighted by Andy. You could technically name them `x.x.1` or `x.1` or `x.x.x.x.1` because you will then never hit the `#.#.#.#` pattern which looks like an IP address. But why getting to this trouble? This means at least you need to configure locally a `.1` TLD, and you enter a lot of nightmares for no benefit. Why not using pure alphabetical hostnames?

Comment: @AndyTurner That was an experiment done by bored geeks one could infer :-) It was evident that it had no future, and that it was un-official. IANA would never delegate such a TLD. It was just showing that it is technically possible. But of very little use, far more too confusing (and even needing a patch on Windows system) for everyone. Other than what happens on the global root, anyone could technically install a purely numeric TLD on its private nameservers to be used on the LAN. Technically ok but really no point in inflicting one so much pain with that case.